# Can't access to attribute of an object in Scala

Tags: scala, jpa, playframework

I have on object `user`. In my view i can retrieve `user.name` `user.email` etc ... 
But I can't retrieve `user.service.name`, it return blank whereas `User.service.id` return id right.

`Service` is an object and `user` and `service` are connected with `@ManyToOne` relation with fetch eager.

Any idea?

I have class `User`

```
Public class User extends Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Public Integer id;
    @Constraints.Required
    @Column(nullable = false)
    Public string nom;
    @Constraints.Required
    Public string password;

    @ManyToOne
    public Service service;
}
```

And class `Service`

```
@Entity
Public class Service extends Model {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     Public Integer id;
     @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
     @Constraints.Required
     public String nom;
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "service")
     Public Set<User> users = new LinkedHashSet<User>();
}
```

And in my `listUser.scala.html` I have this

```
@for(user <- currentPage.getList) {
     <tr>
          <td>@user.nom</td>
          <td>@user.service.nom</td>
     </tr>

}
```

Comment: well, maybe the name is blank? How does the templating mechanism access attributes? If it doesn't use JavaBean getters it might not trigger lazy loading, causing the attributes to be null.